# Entity Framework Skip method running very slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, poco

I'm using Entity Framework 5, ObjectContext and POCOs on my data access layer. I have a generic respository implementation and I have a method that queries the database with paging using Skip() and Take(). Everything works fine, except that the query performance is very slow when skipping a lot of rows (I'm talking about 170k rows)

This is an excerpt of my query on Linq to Entities:

**C# Code:**

```
ObjectContext oc = TheOBJEntitiesFactory.CreateOBJEntitiesContext(connection);
var idPred = oc.CreateObjectSet<view_Trans>("view_Trans").AsQueryable();
idPred = idPred.OrderBy(sortColumn, sortDirection.ToLower().Equals("desc"));
var result = idPred.Skip(iDisplayStart).Take(iDisplayLength);
return new PagedResult<view_Trans>(result, totalRecords);
```

In the translated query to Transact-SQL I noticed that instead of using the **ROW_NUMBER()** clause with the view directly its making a sub-query and applying the **ROW_NUMBER()** to the results of the sub-query...

example:

```
select top(10) extent1.A, extent1.B.extent1.C from (
select extent1.A, extent1.B, extent1.C, 
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[A] DESC) AS [row_number] 
from (
select A,B,C from table as extent1)) as extent1
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 176610
ORDER BY [Extent1].[A] DESC
```

This takes about 165 seconds to complete. Any idea on how to improve the performance of the translated query statement?

Comment: Since the query is fast without the Skip, this suggests that the problem is in the SQL, rather than the other areas of performance consideration in the Entity Framework. Therefore, the first thing I would do is to use SQL Profiler to diagnose why the query is slow. Have you tried this? What did you find?

Comment: I already did that. I think that the problem is in the unnecessary subquery that is being constructed by Entity Framework, when I make the same query using LinqToSql instead of Entity Framework the result is not the same and the query is a lot faster (~30 seconds). If you see the Sql in the example above, there is an unnecessary sub-query to the table and the row_number is not applied to the table, but to the results of that sub-query.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question. The subquery you blame appears in a lot of EF queries which don't take 165s to complete. SQL Profiler should give you more specific information. What, precisely, is causing the 165s?

Comment: In the Query Generated by EntityFramework an the one that I edited the 'Nested Loop' Step is the step that takes more CPU time. But the one that I edited the estimated number of rows is lower than the one generated by EntityFramework... this is how my query looks like:  select extent1.A, extent1.B.extent1.C from (
select extent1.A, extent1.B, extent1.C, 
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[A] DESC) AS [row_number] 
from (
select A,B,C from table as extent1)) as extent1
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 176610 and Extent1.row_number < 176621
ORDER BY [Extent1].[A] DESC

Comment: Instead of a Top(10) I added a row_number < X and that fixed the issue

Comment: I just picked up that you're doing this on a `VIEW`; I wonder if that's part of the problem here? As an experiment, could you try it directly on the underlying table(s) and see if that's involved? Nothing really wrong with your fix except I don't know how to make EF generate that SQL, and I want to figure out why your specific case is so atypical.

Comment: Yes it's a view and with a lot of left outer joins, sorry, I forgot to say that. But the view has no functions or subqueries, just a few tables with left joins. I made the same query just with the big table (without the joins) and yes, it seems that the problem is with the left joins. The query last less than 1 second.

Comment: OK, now you're getting somewhere. Run that query through the database tuning advisor and see what it recommends.

Comment: Anyway I think that It shouldn't be that slow because the order by row is the primary key of the big table in the view.

Comment: I just ran the query with SQL Tunning Advisor and created two indexes recommended by the tool. now the Query is FAST and that solved my problem. But anyway I think that the generated query by entity famework should be improved. Have you checked the query generated by LinqToSql?

Comment: @Boanerge: using row_number < X, instead Top(10), increase performance, i tested it, but how do you implement it in EF?

Answer (score 3):

For those not following the comments above, I suspected the problem was not the extra `SELECT`, since that extra `SELECT` is present on many, many EF queries which do not take 165s to run. I eventually noticed that his ObjectSet referenced a `VIEW` and wondered if that might be part of the problem. After some experimentation, he narrowed the problem down to a `LEFT JOIN` inside the view.  I suggested that he ran the Database Tuning Advisor on that query; he did, and the two indices suggested fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the slowness is probably that your sql is ordering your rows twice.

To control the query, the only option I know of is to call idPred.SqlQuery("Select ...", params).  This will allow you to write your own optimized query for the data request.

Comment: If you're going to vote me down, could you please comment to let me know what's wrong with my answer?