# Entity Framework Take statement, cause EF generates unefficient SQL query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first, paging

I'm using `Take` and `Skip` statements in EF CodeFirst, for implementing Paging(as  [Zoran Maksimovic](http://www.agile-code.com/blog/author/zoran/) said in [this post](http://www.agile-code.com/blog/entity-framework-code-first-filtering-and-sorting-with-paging-)), these statements cause EF generate a sql query like this(my page size is 100):

```
 SELECT TOP (100) [Filter1].[Id]                AS [Id],
                  [Filter1].[SendDuration]      AS [SendDuration]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],               
                       [Extent1].[SendDuration] AS [SendDuration],
                       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[SendDuration] DESC) AS [row_number]
                       FROM   [dbo].[MyView] AS [Extent1]
                       WHERE  (1293>= [Extent1].[Id])
                )AS [Filter1]
                WHERE  [Filter1].[row_number] > 500
                ORDER  BY [Filter1].[SendDuration] DESC
```

but this sql is so slow, when run in sql server, but as [Boanerge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015496/boanerge) said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401218/entity-framework-skip-method-running-very-slow#comment23556838_16401218) using `row_number < X` instead of `Top(y)` cause performance increase. i mean that if i change the generated sql to:

```
     SELECT  [Filter1].[Id]                AS [Id],
                  [Filter1].[SendDuration]      AS [SendDuration]
        FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],               
                       [Extent1].[SendDuration] AS [SendDuration],
                       row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[SendDuration] DESC) AS [row_number]
                       FROM   [dbo].[MyView] AS [Extent1]
                       WHERE  (1293>= [Extent1].[Id])
                )AS [Filter1]
                WHERE  [Filter1].[row_number] > 500 and [Filter1].[row_number] <= 600
                ORDER  BY [Filter1].[SendDuration] DESC
```

query execution time will be better and more acceptable(in some cases 4 or 5 time more faster).
Is there any way to force EF to generate 2nd Sql instead 1st Sql?

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your full schema etc. it's hard to be certain but to me this indicates a missing index<sup>1</sup>.

Run the query with include actual execution plan and see what SSMS tells you - it often suggest an extra index.

I've got one dataset that is millions of records - and spent about 3 days optimising each query using LINQpad, SSMS and detailed analysis of the execution plan. In the end I managed to save around 96% execution time just by adding 3 extra indexes.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's a clue that indexing is required/would help when you can restrict the range and improve the performance - as that's indicating that a scan is being performed and we don't like scans...

Comment: SSMS suggest an extra index, and i add it, but the result doesn't differ.

Comment: but when i change the suggested index by SSMS(remove some include columns that suggested by SSMS), it became better.

Comment: Take that which SSMS tells as the starting point; try it; rerun the query etc.. until performance is acceptable. If you're not an expert DBA what SSMS tells  you is helpful - but indexing isn't always easy. @Masoud - what improvements are you seeing?

Comment: query execution time decrease to 2-3 seconds from 8-9 seconds

Answer (score 1):

This is the double edge of algorithmic query generation: the query is only as good as the algorithm. The only way for that to change is if the algorithm decides to do something different - perhaps with a different version of the ORM tool. Of course, "different" is not always the same as "better" :)

For non-trivial queries, an experienced SQL developer will - when armed with the right tools (SSMS provides most of what you would need) - often be able to out-perform many generated queries. Of course, a less experienced SQL developer may end up with the query doing *the wrong thing*.

Most ORMs offer the option to pass a raw SQL query into the engine - this does lose portability, though. If that is a problem, another option is things like stored procedures, where the API could be similar even on different implementations on different databases.

The questions you need to ask here are:

- do I genuinely target more than one database provider?
- am I happy to own the ongoing maintenance of this query?

If the answers as "no" and "yes", you should be ok to just pass a raw SQL (presumably T-SQL) query to EF.